# Java applets: Capturing the mouse's coordinates every time they change

Tags: java, applet, mouse

Apparently, my Java teacher at school doesn't know that the mouseMooved and mouseDragged events activate every few milliseconds. I had to find that myself while exercising events.

I am trying to make an applet in which you can draw stuff. Currently I can draw with a small filled circle. When I move the mouse too fast, big dots appear get drawn, instead of lines. That's because the mouseDragged event gets called every few milliseconds. I want to make the two events to get called EVERY time when the coordinates of the mouse change, no matter the speed.

I have no idea how to do that. Nor I know if the proper solution is by decreasing the interval between every capture, after overriding a certain method.

How can I capture the coordinates of the mouse's location absolutely every time they change?

EDIT:

Apparently I can't make the applet capture the coordinates every time they change. Can I decrease the time between the captures (can I increase the speed of capturing) somehow?

Comment: *"How can I capture the coordinates of the mouse's location absolutely every time they change?"*  You can't, deal with it.  Instead, store the points in a [`GeneralPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) and draw the path.  The points will be 'joined up'.

Comment: I don't believe it can be done (it can't certainly be done within Java and I doubt event a JNI solution would work).  This is system dependent and the system is likely perform some coalescing of the events in order to reduce the risk of swamping applications.  Show us some code and we might be able to help you with a solution